# How long does it take to get an application reviewed for Ubuntu?

Tags: package-management, application-development, application-submission

I submitted a package around three weeks ago, and so far it's status is still "Pending"

Comment: Do you mean the software center? Ubuntu one is a personal cloud service.

Comment: I mean for the Ubuntu App Store

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you can get the status of the reviews here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-app-review-board

Of particular interest is I noticed a comment on this one:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-app-review-board/+bug/763937

It looks like the review process is taking unusually long at the moment as there was some change in the internal tools. As such, I don't think your experience will be typical compared to past review times.

Answer (score 1):

The **ARB team** is still doing their best to optimize their work, as they are aware of the fact that the reviews take lots of time, and very often it discourages developers. Though as the tools (e.g. *MyApps* portal) are now more or less ready, I expect things to speed up a bit. However, it is still likely that the process may take **several weeks** or **even months**.

Comment: Months? It definitely discourage a lot of developers. Either reject or approve should have a time range.