# ubuntu App Store: waiting 4+ months now for approval/review?

Tags: software-center, application-submission

I submitted my application to Ubuntu App Store ( http://developer.ubuntu.com/ ) almost 5 months ago.
It is still waiting for approval or review.  So far no comments, or any evidence that anything at all is happening on the app store.

My application is "TripleA", which has been around for 10+ years on Linux.  We are open source and free ( http://triplea.sourceforge.net/ ).
I normally make a new stable release twice per year, and we are still a fairly popular application (around 10,000 downloads per month from our website).

I believe is an old version of TripleA is already on the Ubuntu App store, someone told me it was version 1.3.2.2 or something, which is about 2 years old.  Our latest version was released a month ago and is version 1.6.1.4.

So what is the hold up on the review/approval for our app?

I didn't see any contact-us page, or complaint page, or any way for me to get any attention and alert the people who run the app store that I am still waiting.
If this is not the correct place to request a review, then please tell me where or how to get this done.

thanks,
Veqryn

Comment: The latest version of Ubuntu (Raring) has the latest version of your game: http://packages.ubuntu.com/triplea

Comment: Questions that only Canonical staff members or certain Ubuntu developers can answer are off-topic. We're just a community of Ubutnu users, after all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/65544/how-long-does-it-take-to-get-an-application-reviewed-for-ubuntu?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

The [App Review Board](http://developer.ubuntu.com/community/app-review-board-charter/) as of now is undergoing a transition and package reviews can go at a slow pace so kindly bear with us. In the meantime, since the package is maintained in the repositories of Debian and Ubuntu, [file a package upgrade request](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs).

In future, in case of any concerns regarding app development in ubuntu, please feel free to join `#ubuntu-app-devel` on irc.freenode.net so that we can help you out.

Answer (score 1):

This application is already in debian and ubuntu, and up to date.  You don't have to do anything.